# unit testing for portable class library

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I am building a universal portable library (a dll for universal apps: windows 8.1 & WP 8.1) and I want to add a unit test project to the solution.

I have added a Unit Test Library (windows) project to the solution and the tests are discovered in the test explorer and the unit tests work just fine. But i can't test the dll for Windows Phone.

I have tried a Coded UI Test Project (windows Phone). The test are discovered in test explorer but i can not test async methods. The debugger says
Result StackTrace:

> at VeePlayUnitTests.WindowsPhone.CodedUITest1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

And if i try the Unit Test App (windows Phone), it does not get discovered by test explorer. I am using VS2013 U4.

What am i missing? How do I run a unit test for WP for a universal portable lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of configuring and playing around with my solution i finally got it working. I don't remember exactly what i did (i remember that the default unit test template is configured wrong). All i can say is that the solution lays in configuring the Configuration Manager correctly for your unit test and the app/lib you are testing. and configure the build properties of the test unit project. What correctly means will depend on what you (and on what device) you are testing. This helped : http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.ro/2013/06/x86arm-configuration-gotcha-in-windows.html

Comment: Hi ,

This is the first time I am starting the unit testing integration.

So Could you please help me by giving the steps of process what all you did to achieve unit test work.
Have to be done for Win 8.1 PCL